how to trace the target run with Frida
My thought is that since Frida can trace the execution of basic blocks, I could use it to calculate code coverage. How can I compute this? My code script doesn’t seem to be correct—how should I modify it? Are there other solutions? I hope someone can help answer these questions.
why my code do not work? it can not trace the block.
i want to get the edge coverage. please help me!

var mainModule = Process.enumerateModules()[0];
let mainSymbol = DebugSymbol.fromName('main');
let mainAddr = mainSymbol ? mainSymbol.address : null;

if (mainAddr === null) {
    console.error("Failed to find the 'main' symbol.");
}

console.log(mainAddr)
const edgeCov = new Int8Array(65536).fill(0);
let pre = 1;

Interceptor.attach(mainAddr, {
    onEnter: function (args) {
        const threadId = Process.getCurrentThreadId();

       
        Stalker.trustThreshold = 0; 
        Stalker.follow(threadId, {
            events: {
                block: true,      
                compile: true     
            },
            onEvent: function (type, event) {
                if (type == 'compile') {
                    const blockStart = event.address.toUInt32();  
                    const index = (pre ^ blockStart) % 65536;
                    
                    edgeCov[index]++;
                    pre = (index << 1);
                }
            }
        });
    },
    onLeave: function (args) {
        
        let sum = 0;
        let nonZeroCount = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < edgeCov.length; i++) {
            sum += edgeCov[i];
            if (edgeCov[i] !== 0) {
                nonZeroCount++;
            }
        }

        console.log("Edge coverage sum:", sum);
        console.log("Non-zero entries:", nonZeroCount);
    }
});


i try to run
 frida -f test -l fridacov.js
and get
Spawning `test`...                                                      
0x562104cd12d0
Spawned `test`. Resuming main thread!                                   
Thread 0: Shared variable = 20
Thread 1: Shared variable = 40
Thread 3: Shared variable = 60
Thread 2: Shared variable = 100
Thread 4: Shared variable = 80
Final shared variable value: 100
Error: expected a pointer
    at value (frida/runtime/core.js:454)
    at onEnter (~/Desktop/code/Test/fridacov.js:34)[Local::test ]->
Edge coverage sum: 0
Non-zero entries: 0
Process terminated
[Local::test ]->

Thank you for using Frida!

